# Assets Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, asset-pipeline

I've got an issue with assets pipeline in production mode. I ran`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`in development and it works fine. However when I ran it in production server(after deployment), the css and js files can not be loaded properly. When I access css or js files through url `/assets/[file_name]`, I get 500 error. I thought it's a permission issue but all files under `/public/assets` can be accessible. Production.rb and development.rb files are all intact(from scaffolding). I can see all the files listing in the html though. Any hint would be much appreciated. Thanks

production.rb:

```
# Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

Gemfile(snapshot):

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

gem 'pg'
gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
#  gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'compass-rails'
# Deployment related
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-ext'

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'guard'
end
```

Application.css:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require bootstrap.scss
 *= require bootstrap-responsive.scss
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

I have another application.css.scss for sass related:

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/utilities/tables";

.ftr-ticker {
  background: #333;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
....
```

Comment: Can you post your `application.js` and `application.css` ?

Comment: I have updated the question with more info:)

Answer (score 1):

You have modified a manifest file `application.css` and I think that gives a problems . My advice is to rename your `scss` file to other name , not `application` (might be `custom.css.scss`) and include it in the manifest `application.css` file like this:

```
*= require custom
```

As you can see , the names of stylesheet files are not prefixed . Your `*= require bootstrap.scss` should be `*= require bootstrap` . I suggest also to move `require_tree` after all others requires. [This Railsguide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) is going to help you with asset-pipeline in Rails 3.2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have tried your solution but to no avail. I guess it's more like the path error as I can see something like `/assets/application-[hash].css` in the html but cannot open it. The file does exists and has content though. Is it weird? This is my first time dealing with assets pipeline actually, sorry if it sounds newbie

Comment: The hash-like names are OK , these are precompilled assets , I guess you are trying to get them on the server , but you can't . I would advice you to remove your `public/assets` from your development and not to precompile assets by hand , it messes the dev process . The capistrano task handles the precompilation fine . Can you show where you have placed your `css.scss` files?

Comment: Thanks alot Qumara SixOneTour, I found the problem . It is actually in the virtualhost setup, the public/assets folder was not proxied to the backend properly. I will still kudo you for the willingness though:D